# Animated card effect slider using swiper React JS

Tags: reactjs, slider

I'm trying to create an animated slider in React JS and I'd like to use swiper and achieve a card effect animation: https://swiperjs.com/.

[image]

Here's my code, but it works like a normal slider:

```
import EffectCards from "./swiper/modules/effect-cards/effect-cards.js";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";
import "swiper/css/effect-cards";

const ITEMS = [
  { src: require("./assets/one.jpeg") },
  { src: require("./assets/two.jpeg") },
  { src: require("./assets/three.jpeg") },
  { src: require("./assets/four.jpeg") },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-screen h-screen bg-slate-900">
      <Swiper
        // install Swiper modules
        modules={[EffectCards]}
        spaceBetween={50}
        slidesPerView={1}
        cardsEffect={{
          rotate: 50,
        }}
        onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
        className="w-[200px] h-screen"
      >
        {ITEMS.map((item) => {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide>
              <div className="w-[200px] h-[300px]">
                <img src={item.src} alt="image" className="w-full h-full" />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

---

Comment: Thank you, what if I join patron and after one month cancel it, to get the resources, can I do it?

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/demos

Comment: If you click on them, 404 not found.

Comment: i am sorry. but you can search on sandbox or github to find source code

Comment: https://uiinitiative.com/

Comment: I have updated my question, if you have some suggests. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here's how you could do it:

You have to add effect="cards" in the Swiper Component

```
import {EffectCards} from "swiper/modules";
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/bundle';

const YourSwiperComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Swiper
            modules={[EffectCards]}
            slidesPerView={1}
            effect="cards"
            onSlideChange={() => {}}
            onSwiper={() => {}}
        >
            { /* Your .map() */}
            
            <SwiperSlide>
                { /* your slide */}
            </SwiperSlide>
        </Swiper>
    )
}
```